# Retrofit a Hi-Fi remote with a RF 433 MHz module

Tags: rf, infrared, modulation, remote-control

In the past I used a remote for a AIWA Hi-Fi to control a AVR processor and circuit I custom made. I used an infrared receiver from Vishay (tuned on the 38 kHz) to demodulate the signal, then fed to the AVR (custom board, not Arduino).

The remote I have uses NEC protocol (http://www.vishay.com/docs/80071/dataform.pdf and https://techdocs.altium.com/display/FPGA/NEC+Infrared+Transmission+Protocol) that is based on pulse distance encoding.

The circuit controls fluorescent lighting (selection of lamp and intensity)  in the living room and I found that it has some problems with interferences from the fluorescent tubes. The software already discards most of them but I'd like to improve it.

I would like to use the same remote (due to the multiple and nice looking buttons) but retrofit it with a 433 MHz transmitter.

Would one of the cheap 433 MHz emitters accept the signal meant for the IR LED, after a proper low-pass filter to remove the 38 kHz modulation? or would the 38 kHz modulated signal already work with the transmitter?

On the receiving side I have more freedom and I can put a demodulation circuit if needed, only the remote is space and electronics constrained, that is why I would like the simplest possible solution for the transmitter.

**Edit**

Clarified protocol and encoding

Comment: Can you detail the data stream sent? Also you can't low pass filter away a carrier from a modulated carrier so maybe you can detail what you actually mean here?

Comment: NEC protocol, pulse distance encoding.

Comment: @OlafM: How are you planning to implement demodulation of the 433MHz carrier on the Rx-Side? I am just curious. For my own project I have searched all over the web for a demodulation module for 455MHz, but could not find anything new, just the obsolete Vishay TSOP7000.

Comment: I thought about the receiver mentioned in the answer, but I haven't checked the details. This could be useful too: https://forum.pilight.org/Thread-Interfacing-with-IR-remote-controls In any case, I can also accept the 38 kHz signal as it is and do the rest of the processing via software. Check http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36328/how-to-demodulate-an-ir-signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there's a good chance that the 38 kHz modulation works directly with a 433 MHz transmit module. It so happens that both IR and 433 MHz use the same [OOK modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-off_keying) at 38 kHz. So I would say that it **would not work** if you removed the 38 kHz signal !

A simple receiver module (BTW get one **with** an AGC on it [like this one](http://www.quasaruk.co.uk/acatalog/QFM-RX1-500.gif))
will get rid of the 38 kHz for you, the same as that the IR receiver (which is currently in your AVR processor) will do.

I think you can just replace both transmitter and receiver and it should just work. No additional filter is needed.

Comment: I specified the remote uses NEC (pulse distance encoding). I guess your answer still is valid.

Comment: That sort of comes "on top of" the 38 kHz !

Comment: That's why I thought your answer was still valid...